Bpy: Traversing the side of a 2d connected edge set
Background: Keping an even thickness on a 3d curve is tricky, so i want to throw together a python script that solidifies a 2d edge set, giving it an outline with a even thickness.
To create a foundation for that, we first need to be able traverse the left (or right) side of connected edges.
On itself this would require identifying connected edges, but there are some edge cases i don't know how to deal with.

Intersections: a vertex may be connected to multiple edges, and we need to traverse the one with the smallest opening angle (?)
Two sides: if an edge ends, we need to continue on the other side of it in the same direction


A set of lines and the found points (red or green depend whether we start outside or inside). These are offset along the normal, but that is not necessary.
Efficiency is not important, any help is appreciated!
